# Validate at least one in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a validate so is selected at least one provider of the 6 options I have.

I am trying to use this:

```
validate :at_least_one_provider
def at_least_one_provider
  unless [ticket_provider_name, ticket_provider_name_2, ticket_provider_name_3, ticket_provider_name_4, ticket_provider_name_5, ticket_provider_name_6].any?{|val| val.present? }
    errors.add :base, 'You need at least one provider!'
  end
end
```

But seems that is only working if I have the first name selected (then the error is not appearing) but if I select for example provider 2 and not provider 1 I see the error.

I have tried also something like this for each provider:

```
 validates :ticket_provider_name, presence: true, if: "!ticket_provider_name_2.blank? || !ticket_provider_name_3.blank? || !ticket_provider_name_4.blank? || !ticket_provider_name_5.blank? || !ticket_provider_name_6.blank?", length: {maximum: 255}
```

Any idea how can I get this to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
def at_least_one_provider
  unless ticket_provider_name || ticket_provider_name_2 ||  ticket_provider_name_3 || ticket_provider_name_4 || ticket_provider_name_5 || ticket_provider_name_6
    errors.add :base, 'You need at least one provider!'
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems that is not doing anything. I dont see the error with or without any provider. I see: undefined method `|' for "":String

Comment: Those should be double pipes `||` (OR operator). Fixed

Comment: Thanks, with that I dont get any error and I can upload the concert without any provider :S.

Answer (score 0):

Use `compact` to remove all nil elements, then check if there are any values remaining. Having at least one non-nil element will result in a non-empty array and pass the validation.

```
validate :at_least_one_provider
def at_least_one_provider
  # for clarity
  provider_names = [ticket_provider_name, ticket_provider_name_2, ticket_provider_name_3, ticket_provider_name_4, ticket_provider_name_5, ticket_provider_name_6]

  # remove nils and fail validation if nothing left
  if provider_names.compact.empty?
    errors.add :base, 'You need at least one provider!'
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

Since you are using form input, blank fields will be empty strings rather than nil. Using the same strategy as above, remove blank strings instead of nils:

```
validate :at_least_one_provider
def at_least_one_provider
  # for clarity
  provider_names = [ticket_provider_name, ticket_provider_name_2, ticket_provider_name_3, ticket_provider_name_4, ticket_provider_name_5, ticket_provider_name_6]

  # remove blank strings and fail validation if nothing left
  if provider_names.reject(&:blank?).empty?
    errors.add :base, 'You need at least one provider!'
  end
end
```

Comment: This is not doing anything. I don't see any error even if there is no any provider. Thanks!

Comment: Probably because your empty values are blank strings rather than nils. Check my edit and try again.

Comment: I have tried with your edit code and is very strange. Is still only working if I have the first provider_name selected. If I tried to insert the form with the second provider I see the error "You need at least one provider!". I have same problem with other codes I tried. Only working with the first provider.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here... Are the six variables coming from six separate text fields?